# How to group and count based on two column values in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has two columns type and name.

```
               Type               Name
0             Third               Jake
1            Second               Tang
2            Second               Rose
3             Other               Rose
4            Second               Jake
5             First                Sam  
6             First                Tom
```

How can I group both the columns-  type and name and have result like this:

```
Name    First  Second  Third  Other
Jake     0       1       1      0
Tang     0       1       0      0
Rose     0       1       0      1
Sam      1       0       0      0 
Tom      1       0       0      0
```

Please suggest!

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Type'])`

Comment: Thanks @Erfan. Yes, with pd.crosstab, able to group name and type. thanks.